# Can the Omni-Channel Utility Item be deployed as part of a Custom App

Tags: metadata-api, omnichannel, utility-bar

I included the Omni-Channel Utility Item as part of my custom app in my scratch org, but don't see it in my app-meta.xml file when retrieving it using sfdx cli. I want to include this utility item in the custom app source code so that it deploys pre-configured without having to do this as a manual step in our upper environments. Is this possible or do I have to continue with manual configuration after each code deployment?

Answer (score 0):

It should be under flexipages. I was able to push it via github
Attaching the screenshot of the same
[image]